# Desperately need help on Rx.Net

Tags: c#, wpf, system.reactive

Hi guys i'm very very very new to Rx and trying to put together a simple test app. It basically subscribes to the window click event using Rx and sets the text on a textbox to "Clicked". It's a wpf app. Here's the xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Reactive.MainWindow"  
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"  
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"  
      Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">  
   <Grid>  
      <Canvas>  
        <TextBlock Name="txtClicked" Text="Rx Test"/>            
    </Canvas>  
 </Grid>
```

and here's the code behind:

```
using System;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Windows;  
using System.Windows.Input;  

namespace Reactive  
{
  /// <summary>  
  /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml  
  /// </summary>  
public partial class MainWindow : Window  
{  
    /// <summary>  
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MainWindow"/> class.  
    /// </summary>  
      public MainWindow()  
      {  
        InitializeComponent();  

        var xs = from evt in Observable.FromEvent<MouseEventArgs>(this, "MouseDown")
                 select evt;

        xs.ObserveOnDispatcher().Subscribe(value => txtClicked.Text = "Clicked");
    }
}
}
```

But for some reason the code doesn't run. i get the message:

> The invocation of the constructor on type 'Reactive.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9

InnnerException message:

> The event delegate must be of the form void Handler(object, T) where T : EventArgs.

Please help!!!

Comment: May be u can get help from the following samples. http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc6

Answer (score 4):

Probably too late, but I suggest that you use the strongly-typed `FromEventPattern` method whenever you want an observable from an event.

```
IObservable<IEvent<TEventArgs>> FromEventPattern<TDelegate, TEventArgs>(
    Func<EventHandler<TEventArgs>, TDelegate> conversion,
    Action<TDelegate> addHandler,
    Action<TDelegate> removeHandler)
    where TEventArgs: EventArgs
```

In your code you would use it like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window  
{  
    /// <summary>  
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MainWindow"/> class.  
    /// </summary>  
    public MainWindow()  
    {  
        InitializeComponent();  

        var xs = Observable
            .FromEventPattern<MouseButtonEventHandler, MouseButtonEventArgs>(
                h => (s, ea) => h(s, ea),
                h => this.MouseDown += h,
                h => this.MouseDown -= h);

        _subscription = xs
            .ObserveOnDispatcher()
            .Subscribe(_ => txtClicked.Text = "Clicked");
    }

    private IDisposable _subscription = null;
}
```

Also you should use a subscription variable (or subscriptions list) to hold the `IDisposable` returned from the `Subscribe` call. And just like removing an event handler when you're closing down your form, you should also dispose of your subscription too when you're done.

Answer (score 2):

I can't check right now, but I believe the problem is you're using the wrong `EventArgs` class. The `Window.MouseDown` event is of type `MouseButtonEventHandler`, so you should use `MouseButtonEventArgs`:

```
var xs = Observable.FromEvent<MouseButtonEventArgs>(this, "MouseDown");
```

(Your query expression wasn't really doing anything in this case - you can put it back if you want to add where clauses etc.)